# How to show hide divs INSIDE divs easily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website is a blog where I have a page with all the posts on a single HTML page. The "posts" are just images inside divs and I need some information to be able to show and hide in side the parent div of the images. Heres how its set up:

HTML

```
<div class="posts">
    <h3>mm/dd/yy<p class="preview">click to show more</p><p class="expand">click to show less</p></h3>
    <h4>Title</h4><br>
    <p class="expand">caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption</p>
    <div class="centertext">
        <img class="post" src="path/to/image">
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

lil CSS

.expand{display: none;}

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".posts").click(function(){
    $('.expand').toggle();
    $('.preview').toggle();
});
```

What ends up happening that I don't want to happen is that all images and their captions are hiding and showing when I just click one. Shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yLbq2nom/3/) or fullscreen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yLbq2nom/3/embedded/result/) Someone please help me! Additional info: I am  using JQuery and Bootstrap too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".posts").click(function () {
        $(this).find('.expand').toggle();
        $(this).find('.preview').toggle();
    });

});
```

Or more simple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".posts").click(function () {
            $(this).find('.expand, .preview').toggle();
        });

    });
```

To toggle means, that you don't know the state. The best way is, to change a css-class or a data-attribute.

Comment: I'm new to JS so thanks a lot! Had no idea this existed.

Comment: The point is, you don't read the documentation and you are just trying to get the the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.target/this to refer the current object clicked and find child(expand/preview) of the object you clicked with find() 
or

check for the children if it is .expand/.preview with function is()   //not a better approach

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".posts").click(function () {
        $(this).find('.expand').toggle();
        $(this).find('.preview').toggle();
    });
});

or

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".posts").click(function (event) {
        $(event.target).find('.expand').toggle();
//check if target is .expand or its child then first go to its parent with .parents().eq() then apply find()
        $(event.target).find('.preview').toggle();
//check if target is .preview or its child then first go to its parent with .parents().eq() then apply find()
    });
});
```